# Erro ao abrir conexão com um banco SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Estou com um problema para abrir uma conexão com um banco de dados local em SQL Server 2008 R2.

O método de abertura que está dando erro é o seguinte:

```
public static SqlConnection AbreConexao()
{
    string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    _DataSource = INI.LerINI(@path + "\\ConfigDB.ini", "DataSource");
    _InitialCatalog = INI.LerINI(@path + "\\ConfigDB.ini", "InitialCatalog");
    _UserId = INI.LerINI(@path + "\\ConfigDB.ini", "UserId");
    _Password = INI.LerINI(@path + "\\ConfigDB.ini", "Password");

    connString = "Data Source=" + _DataSource + ";Initial Catalog=" + _InitialCatalog + ";User Id=" + _UserId + ";Password=" + _Password + "";            

    conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        conn = null;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        Application.Exit();
    }

    return conn;
}
```

A ConnectionString está assim:

```
'Data Source=ADMIN;Initial Catalog=ControleFinanceiro;User Id=Admin\User;Password='
```

No momento da abertura da conexão ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> "Uma conexão com o servidor foi estabelecida com êxito, mas ocorreu um
>   erro durante o processo de logon. (provider: Shared Memory Provider,
>   error: 0 - Não há processo no outro extremo do pipe.)"

Já liberei os protocolos no SQL Configuration Manager para TCP/IP, NamedPipes e Shared Memory.

O check de Permitir conexões remotas na configuração de conexões da DB também está habilitado.

Alguém tem alguma ideia para solucionar?

Comment: Dentro do SQL Server Configuration Manager, em Client Protocols tem a opção de mudar a ordem de conexão, tente colocar a TCP/IP em primeiro, e verifique se o SQL Server está configurado para conexão mista, confira essa string de conexão.

Comment: O TCP/IP fica sempre em segundo, em primeiro o Shared Memory (Só é possível tirar o Shared Memory da primeira ordem desabilitando, fiz o teste assim e o erro persistiu), o SQL está sim configurado para conexão mista.

Answer (score 2):

Essa exception costuma aparecer quando o banco de dados ou usuário especificado está escrito errado ou quando o banco de dados realmente não existe.

Eu também costumo utilizar o seguinte formato de connection string.

`Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;`

Espero ter ajudado.